# How to open console output in new tab?

Tags: rascal

What was the trick to open console output in a new tab in eclipse? (handy for big prints -> no need for scrolling through the tiny console).

Comment: This seems more like an eclipse question. Is it really rascal specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer - I asked prof. Klint, and he knew where it was, so the trick is:

First to `import util::ValueUI;` in your Rascal code, and then - instead of using `print()` or its variants, just use `text()`.
Whatever you prompt to standard output, shall be pushed to a new tab in your Eclipse IDE.